# OpenCV Python Windows : ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to run openCV with python in windows. However I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to import openCV in python. I also installed the unofficial python .whl package from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv for openCV. However I'm still getting this error stating :

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

My Python version is :

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: that mean the module cv2 dont exist or one of his DDLs are missing

Comment: You may have to go long way around and compile your OpenCV library:  https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html or http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/

Comment: Did you install all *OpenCV*'s dependencies (if any)?